# Linear Transformations between isomorphic vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I've been thinking about the set of linear transformations between 2 vector spaces $V$ and $W$ of the same dimension (hence these spaces are isomorphic). 
My main question is: is every element in this set automatically an isomorphism? I feel like this should be false, however I can't think of a counterexample (can't tell if I'm being dense and missing a trivial one). I've also tried to make/find a proof of this statement without any progress. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You missed **the** trivial one! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Just think of the transformation $T(v) = 0_W$, where $0_W\in W$ is the zerovector of $W$. This is obviously linear, but not an isomorphism.

Basically any linear map $T:V\to W$ s.t. $\mathrm{dim}\ \mathrm{Ran} (T) < \mathrm{dim}(W)$ is not an isomorphism.

Comment: Of course! Can't believe I missed the most obvious one. What about non-constant examples?

Comment: @m1820 You can form others, provided $V$ and $W$ are at least $2$-dimensional, by mapping a basis for $V$ to various multiples of a non-zero vector, so long as the multiples are not all $0$. Then you will form a (non-trivial) rank $1$ map that will fail to be invertible.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Cheers for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, but only if you already know that said application is injective or surjective :

Let $u \in W^V$ a linear application, and $n = dim(V) = dim(W)$.

Let $(v_i)_{i\in[|1;n]|}$, a basis for V, then we have that $(u(v_i))_{i\in[|1;n]|}$ is a basis for $W$, this is only is true if $u$ is injective (will provide proof if you need).

If u is injective, let $w = \sum_{k=1}^{n}w_iu(v_i)\in W$, then w can be rewritten as $w=\sum_{k=1}^{n}w_iu(v_i)=u(\sum_{k=1}^{n}w_iv_i)$, therefore, u is surjective as well, which means u is a bijection (ie an isomorphism).

If u is surjective, Im(u) = W, and by the rank-nullity theorem, $dim(Ker(u))+dim(im(u)) = dim(V)= n$ therefore $dimker(u) = n - dim(V) = 0$, which means that $u$ is injective (notice that this theorem could have been used in the case where $u$ was injective).

I'll finish by saying that we have a similar result for "normal" application from one finite set to another :

Let $f\in F^E,$ if $dimE=dimF$, we have an equivalence between the three statements :

(i) $f$ injective

(ii) $f$ surjective

(iii) $f$ bijective

Comment: which means the answer is no, despite what I said in the beginning. If you take any function from a set to another that isnt injective, it wont be an isomorphisme (you can easily build one by playing with the bases)

Comment: If $u$ is injective, then $\{u(v_1),...,u(v_n)\}$ is a linearly independent set, but it need not be a basis a priori. I don't think you can circumvent also invoking the rank-nullity theorem for this direction. Also note that the final theorem you are quoting is only true if the shared dimension of those two vector spaces is finite.

Comment: If both sets are finite, Im positive that we can the rank-nulity theorem for both direction ? Or can't we ?
And isnt there a way to make the injective case work for infinite sets ?

My bad on this one, should I delete ?

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes the rank-nullity theorem would work for both directions of this proof without having to invoke the argument about $ \{(u(v_i)) \}$ being a basis for $W$. (I can't see anything wrong with that argument though). Should've also stated I was referring to finite-dimensional vector spaces in the OP.

Comment: Yes, you can use rank-nullity for both directions. My point is that that is not what you're doing and your argument for the one direction is lacking. It is a priori not obvious that $\{u(v_1),...,u(v_n)\}$ is a generating set. One could argue that it is, because it is a linearly independent set of dimension many vectors in finite dimension, but that should be explicit as it is non-trivial. Also, I'm not sure which "injective case" you mean in the infinite case.